# How to create an Android SoftKeyboard using Custom Layout consisted by Buttons rather than Keyboard (<Keyboard><Row>) Element

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-custom-view

I want to create a `Custom Keyboard` in Android. Which I want to be used as a system keyboard. I have seen many sample projects and tutorials for how to create
custom keyboard using android Keyboard element to build UI part i.e:

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <Row>
      <Key/>
   </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

But, I want to build a `Custom View/UI` using `Buttons` instead of "Keyboard, Rows and Keys" element etc.
And then capture the button's `onTouch` event for input.

Any useful suggestions will be appreciated!

Thanks.